# Reset passwod laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Настроил регистрацию, логин. Но не могу настроить Восстановления пароля.
.env настроил так:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@yandex.ru (тут мой email)
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

При попытки отправить письмо, выдаёт такую ошибку

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.
```

Вот скриншот ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а отправляете почту со своего адреса? или пытаетесь подменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую gmail, и нижеуказанный код отлично работает, попробуйте сменить порт и тип шифровки

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=gmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```